# GAE memcache spin-up time

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, memcached

I am running the same code on two AppEngine installs, the second install is taking significantly longer (~6 seconds) to generate the memcache.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you mean you have two different instance classes? How much memory on each?

Comment: The two machines might be in different server clusters with different loads. Who knows what's going on "under the covers".

Comment: I created different apps, different names, but otherwise identical (all default settings).